# Which approach is better for using Websockets in android applications: async i/o or sync i/o with threads?

Tags: android, websocket, asyncsocket

I am writing a android client which pushes data every 20-30 seconds & also receives updates from server asynchronously.
Since i have other UI components as well, I can't block the main thread.

What are the pros and cons(performance, complexity, maintainability, easy to use API etc..) of using:

1. sync i/o with async task / threads for pushing data to & receiving events from server
2. async nio lib based i/o

Also suggest if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Android and UI apps, you are not only not supposed to block the UI thread, but with newer versions of Android you are simply not allowed to do any networking on the UI thread at all.

Thus, even NIO-based networking on UI thread is usually not a working approach.

For WebSocket, you might want to look at: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid

This does NIO, but on 2 background threads for reader/writer. Notably, it does not do any networking on UI thread .. including connection establishment.

We might rewrite that in the near future to do old-school IO on the background threads since:

a) NIO doesn't buy a lot in this situation
b) implementing TLS over NIO is a PITA

Disclaimer: I am author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: Does using the nio approach / autobahn library inside a messenger service make it any different / better compared to the other approach?

Comment: Not sure if I get what you ask. Fact is, doing _any_ networking on the UI thread - whether NIO or not - will _not_ work on Android. For this reason, Autobahn uses 2 background threads. And currently it does NIO on those, but might do plain blocking IO in the coming future.